# Conversion from wgs-84 to Minnesota state plane(NAD83(NSRS2007) / Minnesota South) gives NaN values

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, pyproj

I am trying to convert latitude and longitude(EPSG:4326) to projected coordinate systems(NAD83(NSRS2007) / Minnesota South).
I followed [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/425685/203867) tutorial.

My code:

```
TRAN_4326_TO_3596 = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3596", always_xy=True)

def mytransform(lon, lat):
  return TRAN_4326_TO_3596.transform(lon, lat)
geo_df[['xproj', 'yproj']] = pd.DataFrame(geo_df.apply(lambda x: mytransform(x['longitude'], x['latitude']), axis=1).tolist(), columns=['foo', 'bar'])
geo_df_sb_cari = geo_df[geo_df["location_name"].isin(["Caribou Coffee", "Starbucks"])]
```

[image]

As you can see in the pic attached I am getting a ton of NaN values for my x and y projections.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend enabling `errcheck=True` as that can provide insight. However, I didn't see an issue when I ran it for one of your points:

```py
>>> tr = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3596", always_xy=True)
>>> tr.transform(-93.328812, 44.913376, errcheck=True)
(852997.3704333376, 312818.1964341999)
```

I would recommend enabling internal PROJ debugging:
https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/advanced_examples.html#debugging-internal-proj

```py
import logging
import os

os.environ["PROJ_DEBUG"] = "2"
logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)s:%(message)s", level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Though, I suspect it has to do with PROJ network issues related to errors downloading transform grids:

- https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/transformation_grids.html
- https://proj.org/usage/network.html